# Open a website inside app using corona

Tags: android, lua, web, coronasdk

I want the user to open website / web page inside app and not in browser. I have a button, which should open a webpage on click.

I am using native.showWebPopup function for this in main.lua. The problem that I am getting is, a white colored page flashes and disappears immediately.

Below is my code. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
function openLink(event)
    if(event.phase == "ended")then

        native.showWebPopup("http://www.google.co.in")

    end
end

btn:addEventListener("touch", openLink)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you check that you've provided access to the internet on Android!
Referring to the documentation: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/native/showWebPopup.html
For Android

> If the web popup is displaying web pages from the Internet, you must add the INTERNET permission to the build.settings file.

```
settings =
{
    android =
    {
        usesPermissions =
        {
            "android.permission.INTERNET",
        },
    },
}
```

Other than that, the syntax looks correct, so I suspect it is a permissions problem.
Hope that helps!